# unable increment id select box after clone (codeigniter)

Tags: jquery

I want to make the id="campaign" increment like campaign1,campaign2,campaign3 etc. but unfortunately I always got campaign1 after click the clone button multiple time .is there anyone How to make the Id increment perfectly? I know I still Beginner at this

any help would be appreciate guys.Thanks

**View html**

```
<select id="campaign" class="form-control" >
   <option value="">- Choose Campaign -</option>
   <option values="1">1</option>
   <option values="2">2</option>
</select>
 <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/add_icon.png" alt="add_icon" id="addCampaign"   class="add-icon">
```

**jquery**

```
$(function() {

    $('#addCampaign').click(function()
        {
            $("#campaign").clone().attr(`id`,`campaign` + $('#campaign').index()).insertAfter('#campaign');
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below snippet
use of same id multiple time is not a good way. You can specify same class to all select so added "campaign" class in select.

then clone last select box and counted number of select box to main id of select box using

```
var count = $(".campaign").length;
```

then appended new select box after last select box using :last selector.

```js
$(function() {

    $('#addCampaign').click(function()
        {
          var count = $(".campaign").length;
          $(".campaign:last").clone().attr(`id`,`campaign` + count).insertAfter('.campaign:last');
        })
        
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="campaign" class="form-control campaign" >
   <option value="">- Choose Campaign -</option>
   <option values="1">1</option>
   <option values="2">2</option>
</select>

  <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/add_icon.png" alt="add_icon" id="addCampaign"   class="add-icon">
```